# Is it necessary to create sitmap for data that is coming from database in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using prisma with NextJS. I am fetching data with dynamic routes. I dont know how SEO and sitemaps works. Do I need to generate sitemap for each post like this `/post/1` ?

Comment: Generally search engines will find you pages themeselves (via internal cross-links in your site). But for SEO purposes better to create it - `sitemap.xml` will will work just as a hint.  Regarding to generating sitemap - you need to do it yourself. Either try some library like `next-sitemap`. But since you sitemap is hardly depends  on DB data, then most likely you need some script or server side logic (that runs by scheduller) and creates `sitemap.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Search engines will find your pages themselves (via internal
> cross-links in your site). But for SEO purposes better to create it -
> sitemap.xml will work just as a hint.
>
> A nice explanation is given by MyTitle in the comment.

I would suggest create a sitemap and add to the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about). Wait for  1-2 days, You will see the change in the google search results. I tried for one of my projects it works quite well.

**Note: try `site: mysite.com` before and after.**